# Fill in a column grouped by condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have table:

| user_id | days_since_install |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 0 |
| 001 | 1 |
| 001 | 1 |

It is necessary to check if there is 1 in the column "days_since_install" in grouping by "user_id" and fill in True in the column "retention_1d" otherwise False.

The resulting table should look like this:

| user_id | retention_1d |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | True |
|  |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do `any`

```
df.groupby('user_id')['days_since_install'].any().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

One option using [`groupby.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
out = (df['days_since_install'].eq(1).groupby(df['user_id']).any()
       .reset_index(name='retention_1d')
      )
```

Output:

```
   user_id  retention_1d
0        1          True
```